# /home error after fresh install laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

So I just fresh installation of Laravel 5 and manage to go to '/' uri with no problem.

But when I go to 'home' as what being listed in default routes.php, I got this error.

```
ErrorException in functions.php line 17:
Missing argument 1 for redirect(), called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/learning-l5/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php on line 43 and defined
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The error states that your missing an argument to redirect(). That does not seem to be related to the rest of your question.

Comment: I would guess you have an ErrorException, in functions.php, on line 17.

Comment: I found the problem. It was caused by my MAMP php.ini file. I was previously set auto_prepend_file = /path/to/file to load my global setting before any request. Thanks